# how to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.String

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to load `kotlin.String` using `SystemClassLoader`

```
        inputClassName = String::class.qualifiedName.toString()
        val input = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
            .loadClass(inputClassName) // here I get error
```

and I'm getting error. Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.String
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at block.execution.Executor.init(Executor.kt:40)
    at block.AppKt.main(App.kt:50)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the kotlin dependencies from your runtime classpath.

Comment: I'm just curious, why there's a need to load String once there's already `String::class`?

Comment: @StephenC No, this will happen even if Kotlin dependencies are in the classpath.

Comment: @MikhailKopylov this is just a simplified example. I need to dynamically load classes that the users asks for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kotlin.String` doesn't exist as a class which can be loaded, it is [mapped to](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types) `java.lang.String` by the compiler. `String::class.java.name` will give you the actual name of the class.

Of course, as Mikhail Kopylov points out, there is little point loading a class by name of an already loaded class. Maybe to load it in a specific `ClassLoader`, but `String` will definitely be loaded by the system class loader anyway.

Comment: Then consider accepting it (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).